# How can i plot a graph using matplotlib.pyplot.plot with an array of Python Objects

Tags: python, json, linux, matplotlib, azure-cosmosdb

This code prints the latency of the write request and saves it into a file, average latency would be one of my X axis and the cost would be Y axis( the cost will be typed in manually)

i need to plot a simple graph that will show me the cost curve in relation to latencies.
but what the problem is when i call the script "obj_array.py" on my terminal what is printed on the terminal does not get saved into a file. and i have no idea how to go further with this

[Terminal Output with python objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2HgJ.png)

```
# initialising pymongo client
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

# Database where the records will be saved - reference to the database
db = client.Kostenanalyse

# Accessing the collection "info_analyse" from the Database
coll = db.info_analyse

#Defining the Start time
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
end = time.perf_counter()

# Opens a file to read current temperature
with open(r"/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp") as File:
        ActualTemp = int(File.readline())/float(1000)


def create_info_data()-> dict:
 
 return {
       "Current Temperature in °C" : ActualTemp,
       "Time when packet was sent" : datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
       "Sensor reading" : "",
       "Latency" : end

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePath = path + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePath, 'a') as fp:
        fp.write( json.dumps(data) + "\n")



counter = 0
#While loop 
while True:
    data = create_info_data()

    start = time.perf_counter()

    coll.insert_one(data)

    end = time.perf_counter() - start
    counter += 1
    print('{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end))
    data = {}
    data['Latency'] = end 
    data['Date & Time'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat() 
    writeToJSONFile('./','latency',data)
    print(counter)
    print(str(start_time) + str(float(ActualTemp)) + 'Wrote data sample {} to collpipection {}'.format(data, 'info'))

    sleep(0.5)
```

This^ **payload.py** writes the objects to a seperate file

and this **obj_array.py** below reads the file and turns them into python objects

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
data = []
with open(r"latency.json") as fp:
    while True:
        l= fp.readline()
        if not l:
            break
            
        j = json.loads( l )
        data.append( j )
pprint( data )
```

Comment: What do you mean? When you run `obj_array.py` your code doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: @Dec0Dedd no obj_array only reads the file. payload.py writes to the file(latency.json) please look again